# UITableView for settings: How to make textboxes and selectboxes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I need to create a grouped UITableView with two cells. In the first one the user must type a customer id, like this from the iPhones settings

[image: Settings - Textbox]

The second is a selectbox, where the user must select it's country like this

[image: Settings - Selectbox]

How can I create cells like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshots do not show a table with two columns, but two different views with a single navigation controller. Maybe [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) helps.

Comment: Thank you. The section `Static Cells` has the solution.